# Using Paid Travis CI for Public Repositories

Tags: travis-ci

I work with an open source project, and would like to take advantage of the extra features provided by the *paid* version of Travis CI, travisci.com.  Unfortunately, it only appears to work for private repositories.

How do I get travisci.com to let me use things like customizeable caching and multiple builds, for a non-private project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

travis-ci.com doesn't support public repositories right now. However, you can get the benefits of caching and full build capacity by using our container-based stack: http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-12-17-faster-builds-with-container-based-infrastructure/

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but I guess it's the correct answer.

Comment: Now that the builds have different timeout features, this answer doesn't seem sufficient: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Timeouts